# Updating callbacks in leaflet-contextmenu

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

### Problem

I am using `leaflet-contextmenu v1.4.0` in `react-leaflet v3.2.1`. The problem is with my code below is that `showColor` never updates when `color` changes.

For example, if `color` is `'blue'` at app initialization, showColor will know `color` is `'blue'`. If `color` changes to `'red'`, `showColor` never updates; it seems to be immutable.

### Question

How can I update callbacks within `leaflet-contextmenu` menu items?

```
const Component = ({ color: string }) => {
  var map = L.map('map', {
    contextmenu: true,
    contextmenuWidth: 140,
    contextmenuItems: [
      {
        text: 'Show color',
        callback: showColor,
      },
    ],
  });
  
  function showColor() {
    alert(color);
  }
};
```

Comment: where is `color` defined? the on in the `Component` is out of scope for the `showColor` function. So `color` in `showColor` must refer to a different variable of the same name defined somewhere else.

Comment: @ChristianFritz - I updated my post to put it in scope. That was a typo.

Comment: Some react-leaflet components need to have their `key` updated when the data changes, or else they do not update reactively. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44221724/1087119.

Comment: Can you change `text: 'Show color'` to `text: color` and see if the context menu item text changes when color updates. If not, my guess is that you can only call `L.map` once on the #map element and all future calls are ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only instantiate the map once, not on every re-render. Instead, just add the context menu item on each re-render.

```
// Only invoke L.map() once
var map = L.map('map', {
    contextmenu: true,
    contextmenuWidth: 140,
});

const Component = ({ color: string }) => {

    // update context menu items anytime color changes
    useEffect(() => {
        map.contextmenu.removeAllItems();
        map.contextmenu.addItem({
          text: 'Show color',
          callback: () => { alert(color) },
        });
    }, [color]);
};
```